# Error loading quantized BERT model from local repository

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

After quantizing the BERT model, it works without any issue. But if I save the quantized model and load, it does not work. It shows an error message: 'LinearPackedParams' object has no attribute '_modules". I have used the same device to save and load the quantized model.

````
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
model.encode(sentences)
quantized_model = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
                model, {torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)
quantized_model.encode(sentences) ```



torch.save(quantized_model, 
       "/PATH/TO/DESTINATION/Base_bert_quant.pt")
model=torch.load("/SAME/PATH/Base_bert_quant.pt")
model.encode(sentences) #shows the error
````